# nw.js: index.html in a parent folder

Tags: node-webkit

The organization of my project's folder is currently as follows:

```
Root folder
| media folders
| js folder
| index.html
| NW folder
```

The `package.json` NW reads is inside the NW folder, which also contains everything in the SDK archive, but whatever I write doesn't seem to point at index.html. I tried both `"main": "./../index.html"` and `"main": "../index.html"`, but neither of them works.

What's the correct way to point at `index.html` in the parent folder? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be putting package.json in the NW folder. Put package.json next to index.html (in the root folder) and run NW.js from that folder. Your `main` would then point to "./index.html".

```sh
cd /your/root/folder
mv "NW folder/package.json" .
"./NW folder/nw" .
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by running NW (we're talking about the exe file, right?) from "that" folder? I used to have the contents of the NW folder at root level, but it didn't feel organized enough.

Comment: I provided an example showing exactly what I meant. Jared also gave you an example that would work. It all depends on whether-or-not you want NW.js in its own directory. I prefer my solution, but Jared's works just as well.

Comment: I do want the NW files to be in their separate folder, and index.html at the root. It makes it easier to use the resources with index being there, I just refer to them with `./js/system.js` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting all of your project files into a `package.nw` folder with the `package.json` inside that. When you open `nw.exe` it will look for a `package.nw` folder next to it, and then try to run the app inside it.

```
YourProject/
  ├── package.nw/
  │   ├── media/
  │   ├── js/
  │   ├── css/
  │   ├── index.html
  │   └── package.json
  ├── locales/
  ├── swiftshader/
  ├── nw.dll
  ├── nw.exe
  └── all the other NW.js files...
```

Then you can just rename `nw.exe` to `MyApp.exe`, customize its icon with [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker), zip up the `YourProject` folder and send it to a buddy to try out. Then all they have to do is "unzip/double-click".